# React-Native: Animated View is preventing the TouchableOpacity's onPress action

Tags: react-native, animation, view, touchableopacity

```
   <Animatable.View animation={'fadeIn'} duration={1000} >
        <TouchableOpacity key={index} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => this.onPress()}>
                <Text>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
   </Animatable.View>
```

Animated `View` is preventing the `onPress` action. If I remove the Animated `View` then `onPress` action works fine.

IF i wrap the content of the `TouchableOpacity` with a `view`, Then `onPress` action works fine.

```
<Animatable.View animation={'fadeIn'} duration={1000} >
    <TouchableOpacity key={index} activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => this.onPress()}>
         <View>
            <Text>Submit</Text>
         <View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</Animatable.View>
```

Can anybody let me know why `AnimatedView` is preventing the `onPress` and how come `View` make `onPress` works?

Comment: are you using react-native-animatable?

Comment: @Ilario, Yes,  `react-native-animatable`